# Extract or view data usage for specific times

Tags: data-monitoring

In Android 4.0 there's data usage I can see how much for date to date was used. I want to see for specific date and only 1h from specific time.

How can I view this already used data usage? *DON'T* post new data usage counters witch will count only from installation. I need to view old data or extract.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible retrospectively.

Comment: @Izzy: "Retrospectively"? Do you mean "retroactively"?

Comment: Well, in that case I'm afraid you only have an option to check with your service provider. Service providers normally keep track of it. No app can track your past data usage. To avoid this trouble in future you should consider a data counter app. :)

Comment: @AlEverett You're probably right -- I'm not a native English speaker, so please forgive me :)

Comment: I want to extract to proove provider i havent used internet while i was out of country. I did try to use but it wasnt connecting but they say thats what ive been using. So i want to get info from phone.

Comment: Retroactively means influencing backward, action going backward, beeing wrongly.
Retrospective is looking in history.